# Jacoco coverage in gradle multimodule with arquillian

Tags: gradle, wildfly, code-coverage, jacoco, jboss-arquillian

I have a multimodule project in gradle with the follow structure

```
root-project:
    rest-module
    cdi-module
    ejb-module
```

From rest-module I call to the others modules, and tests are working fine, but when I run sonarqube task, I only obtain coverage from rest-module and the others is empty. Also I look for "jacoco.exec" file and only exits in rest module.

My configuration of arquillian is:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
<defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />
<container qualifier="wildfly-managed" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="allowConnectingToRunningServer">true</property>
        <property name="jbossHome">C:\wildfly-11.0.0.Final</property>
        <property name="javaVmArguments">-Xms800m -Xmx800m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m</property>
        <property name="outputToConsole">true</property>
 </configuration>  
</container>
<extension qualifier="jacoco">
    <property name="appendAsmLibrary">true</property>
</extension>
<extension qualifier="reporter">
    <property name="report">html</property>
</extension>
```

and the dependies on my subprojets are:

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'project-report'
}

sourceSets {
    test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.jacocoAnt 
     main { 
        output.resourcesDir = "build/classes" 
     }
     test {
        output.resourcesDir = "build/classes" 
     }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation ("org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:1.4.0.Final")
    testImplementation ("org.jboss.arquillian.protocol:arquillian-protocol-servlet:1.4.0.Final")
    testImplementation ("org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-gradle-depchain:3.1.3")
    testImplementation ("org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api-gradle-embedded-archive:3.1.3")
    testImplementation ("org.wildfly.arquillian:wildfly-arquillian-container-managed:2.1.0.Final"
    testImplementation (group: 'org.ow2.asm', name: 'asm', version: '5.0.1')

    //testImplementation "org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-jacoco-with-asm:1.1.0"

    testImplementation ("org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.5"){
        exclude group: "asm", module: "asm"
    }
    testImplementation ("org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-jacoco:1.1.0"){
        exclude group: "asm", module: "asm"
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The question is: How can I see the coverage of the entire project? not just from the rest module